# set umask to 0002 for sftp and scp

Tags: linux, ssh, debian

I want files sent to my server using sftp and scp to be group-writable. How can I do that?

I tried using libpam-umask from http://wiki.debian.org/DebianDesktopHowTo but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think PAM reads the default umask from /etc/login.defs as of Debian 6.0, but I do not currently have access to a system to check on.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to your /etc/pam.d/sshd file and change the umask to whatever you want:

session optional pam_umask.so umask=0002

Comment: Any further details you could share?